# Add slider to plotly heatmap colorbar - R

Tags: r, slider, plotly, ggplotly

I am new to `plotly`. I'm wondering how I could add a slider control to a heat map colour bar that allows the user to only show tiles that are of a specific value/colour? Any tips would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(z = volcano, type = "heatmap")
```

[image]

Comment: you could probably do it in combination with shiny.

Comment: @MLavoie that sounds promising. Could you elaborate? I have used shiny a bit.

Comment: you could use a reactive dataset (filtered by your slider) to create your plot

Comment: @MLavoie cool, thanks. I’ll give it a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the current version of `plotly` (version 4.7.x), there is no way to customize the color bar such that the output plot reacts to it (let alone show specific value of it). There is that `rangeslider()` function, which adds a slider but that doesn't do what you want.

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(z = volcano, type = "heatmap")
rangeslider(p)
```

[image]

I almost feel bad for posting an answer that says "as of yet, it's not possible" but I've actually got in touch with Plotly via email on a very similar issue and the answer from support in regarding to this issue is a "no; not yet."

Comment: Don’t feel bad! At least now I can move on, haha. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think you could get creative and make a slider with multiple traces at different scales.  It's not quite the same, but it might get you close to the desired output.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34883141)